# Localizing variables in express

Tags: node.js, express

I need some help with express:
I have a variable in express that is called lastQuestion, to remember the last question even when assigned across multiple functions.

here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
var lastQuestion;
function sjhda(){
  //uses the variable
  lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
  return(lastQuestion);
}

function asjhasd(){
  //uses the variable
  lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
  return(lastQuestion);
}

function asjhd(){
  //uses the variable
  lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
  return(lastQuestion);
}
```

Let's say that two clients are using the website and this happens:

1: client one starts using the bot, and begins to answer the question (and variable lastQuestion!) "How are you?"
2: client two who is already on generates a new question, and begins to answer the question (while resetting lastQuestion), "What are the odds of death?"
3: client one submits the answer "great". now the answer to the question "What are the odds of death?" has been saved as "great".
How can I fix this? Also, I'd like to avoid using cookies if possible. Thanks!

Comment: each client needs to provide to the server some unique piece of information so that the server can differentiate between clients; you can then map users to their own private `lastQuestion` variable.  this unique information could be one of many things: a user ID variable in your express route, a field in the body of your POST request, a session cookie, etc.  asking about which method to use is probably not a good question for Stack Overflow (though asking for help with whatever method you choose is perfectly fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you would use [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) for.  You can then save state on behalf of one particular user and it won't get mixed up with other users also using the same server.

The basic idea is that when a user comes to your server for the first time, the express-session code drops a cookie on them that the browser will then send back to you on all future requests from that particular browser.  That cookie contains a uniqueID that identifies that particular client on subsequent requests to your server.

Then, the express-session code can also create a stored object that is associated with that particular session id (that is stored in the cookie).  There are lots of different storage drivers for express-session to determine how the actual storage works (database, memory, redis, etc...).  Most people get up and running with the built-in memory store and then work on it later whether they need to move to a persistent store for the session data.

Now, there's an object that is uniquely associated with each user that comes to your site.  Your Express routes can then read and write data to that object, either reading properties from it or adding new properties to it or setting values on existing properties.  Programmatically, you just access it like a Javascript object in `req.session`.

If your site has a login process, then the session can be uniquely tied to a particular logged in user so the same session data will even follow a given loggedin user from one device to the next.  If there's no login, then the session only applies to a particular browser that the user is using which typically works fine for shorter-type session durations where the user doesn't switch devices in the middle of the operation.

FYI, in any nodejs server, you should never store a particular user's state in a common, shared module level or global variable because (as you seem to already know), multiple users will collide, overwriting or inheriting the data from other users.  That's why all data like this should be indexed by some unique identifier that pertains to just that user or client and only accessed through that index.

---

A simple example using express-session would look like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat'}))

app.get("/question", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.lastQuestion);
    if (!req.session.lastQuestion) {
        // send first question
        res.send(...);
    } else {
        // use req.session.lastQuestion to determine which to send next
        res.send(...);
    }
    // update session state to represent the question we just sent
    req.session.lastQuestion = questionWeJustDid;  
});

app.listen(80);
```

Comment: Well, like I said I would like to avoid using cookies (Because I have no previous experience), but this seems to best the best and simplest answer. But because I have never used cookies, could you give me a code example of creating a secure client-specific variable/cookie? Thanks.
Oh, I looked around the internet and it seems the only way to assign i cookie is using document.cookie, which won't work because it's in Node.js and DOM is not usable, right?

Comment: @Oliver - If you use express-session, it will create the cookie for you with default options that are secure (when you use https).  No cookie will be secure without https.  FYI, you set cookies from the server with the [`Set-Cookie` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) on the response.  `document.cookie` is for client access in browser Javascript.

Comment: Ok, but I looked on the NPM and express pages fro express-session, and it looks very complicated. Can you give me a simple example? Thanks!

Comment: @Oliver - Example added to my answer.

Comment: Oh ok! Looks great but one thing, what does "Secret" mean? should I change that?

Comment: @Oliver - Please take a little time to read a couple paragraphs about "secret" in [the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#secret).  Yes, you should change it, but only after you've read in the doc what it is used for.

Comment: I did, but I don't understand what it means when it says "used to sign the session ID cookie." essentially my two questions are: 1: Should I hide the secret in a .env file, and 2: Do I need randomly generated secrets for every client? Thanks.

Comment: The secret should be kept secret.  If your code is open source, then you would keep the secret in something like a .env file that is not available publicly.  If your code is private, then the secret can be in the code.  You use one secret for the server.  Digital signing of the cookie is to detect when it's a valid, non-tampered cookie.  A google search about "digital signing of cookies" will yield more info if you're curious.  Just make up any random phrase or series of characters.

Comment: I used this code:
```app.use(session({
secret: process.env.SECRET,
name: 'session',
cookie: {
sameSite: false,
secure: true,
httpOnly: true
  }
}));```
then this:
```console.log("question: " + req.session.lastQuestion);```

and I get this error:
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ...

sorry for bad code block not sure why it's doing this

Comment: @oliver - I think you've wandered a bit from the original question.  To help you with this new implementation error, we would need to see your new version of the code to see exactly what you're doing wrong.  This error doesn't have anything to do with the express session code.  It comes from trying to send more than one response to the same incoming request.  If you need help with it, please write a new question and show your current version of the code there.

Comment: Ok, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65544373/express-session-error-cant-send-headers-after-they-are-sent

Answer (score 0):

As per the scenario, it is clear that the server needs to know the last question of each user.

You can use JWT Token to know the user's identity. Make a JWT and give it to user after login.

```
/* Suppose JWT Payload looks like this

{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "userId": "id#12",
  "iat": 1516239022
}

*/

let lastQuestion = {}; // You can save and read this Object from cache also.
let user = getDataByJWT(token); //pass token and get the decoded data

function sjhda(){
  //uses the variable
  lastQuestion[user.userId] = generateQuestion();
  return(lastQuestion[user.userId]);
}

function asjhasd(){
  //uses the variable
  lastQuestion[user.userId] = generateQuestion();
  return(lastQuestion[user.userId]);
}

function asjhd(){
  //uses the variable
  lastQuestion[user.userId] = generateQuestion();
  return(lastQuestion[user.userId]);
}
```