# express-session Error: Can't send headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express-session to prevent variable from being global for more than one client, so they don't get tangled up. Here is my *entire* NEW express code:

```
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  name: 'lastQuestion',
  cookie: {
    sameSite: "lax",
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true
  }
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  req.session.lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
    res.render(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {response: "Hello!", question: req.session.lastQuestion, instructions: true});
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);

app.post("/prompt", (req, res) => {
    console.log("New prompt: " + req.body.inputOne);
  req.session.lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
    res.render(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {response: evaluatePrompt(req.body.inputOne.toLowerCase()), question: req.session.lastQuestion, instructions: false});
});

app.post("/answer", (req, res) => {
    console.log("New answer: " + req.body.inputTwo);
  console.log(req.body.question + req.session.lastQuestion);
  analyzeConversationAndWriteToLTM(req.session.lastQuestion, req.body.inputTwo);
  //Line above this /\ /\ /\ /\
  req.session.lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
    res.render(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {response: "Hello!", question: req.session.lastQuestion, instructions: false});
});

app.post("/regenerate", (req, res) => {
  req.session.lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
    res.render(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {response: "Hello!", question: req.session.lastQuestion, instructions: false});
});
```

entire OLD code:

```
3     const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
1414      const express = require("express");
1515      const app = express();
1616      const session = require('express-session');
17  - var lastQuestion;
1817     
1918      app.use(session({
2019        secret: process.env.SECRET,
21  -   name: 'session',
20  +   name: 'lastQuestion',
2221        cookie: {
23  -     sameSite: false,
22  +     sameSite: "lax",
2423          secure: true,
2524          httpOnly: true
2625        }
2726      }));
@@ -31,34 +30,31 @@
3130      app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
3231      app.set('view engine', 'html');
3332     
3433      app.get('/', (req, res) => {
35  -     res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
36  -   lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
34  +   req.session.lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
35  +     res.render(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {response: "Hello!", question: req.session.lastQuestion, instructions: true});
37  -     res.render(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {response: "Hello!", question: lastQuestion, instructions: true});
3836      });
3937     
4038      app.listen(process.env.PORT);
4139     
4240      app.post("/prompt", (req, res) => {
4341          console.log("New prompt: " + req.body.inputOne);
44  -     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
45  -   lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
42  +   req.session.lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
43  +     res.render(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {response: evaluatePrompt(req.body.inputOne.toLowerCase()), question: req.session.lastQuestion, instructions: false});
46  -     //res.render(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {response: evaluatePrompt(req.body.inputOne.toLowerCase()), question: lastQuestion, instructions: false});
4744      });
4845     
4946      app.post("/answer", (req, res) => {
5047          console.log("New answer: " + req.body.inputTwo);
51  
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
52     console.log(req.body.question + lastQuestion);
53    analyzeConversationAndWriteToLTM(lastQuestion, req.body.inputTwo);
54     lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
48     console.log(req.body.question + req.session.lastQuestion);
49   analyzeConversationAndWriteToLTM(req.session.lastQuestion, req.body.inputTwo);
50     req.session.lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
51     res.render(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {response: "Hello!", question: req.session.lastQuestion, instructions: false});
55  -     res.render(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {response: "Hello!", question: lastQuestion, instructions: false});
5652      });
5753     
5854      app.post("/regenerate", (req, res) => {
59  -   lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
60  -     res.render(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {response: "Hello!", question: lastQuestion, instructions: false});
55   req.session.lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
56     res.render(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {response: "Hello!", question: req.session.lastQuestion, instructions: false});
6157      });
```

And analyzeConversationAndWriteToLTM:

```
function analyzeConversationAndWriteToLTM(unrefinedFirstStatement, unrefinedSecondStatement){
  updateLTMArrays();
  var firstStatement = unrefinedFirstStatement.toLowerCase().replace(punctuation,"");
  var secondStatement = unrefinedSecondStatement.toLowerCase().replace(punctuation,"");
  if(prompts.includes(firstStatement) || secondStatement == "new question" || secondStatement == "newquestion" || secondStatement == "" || secondStatement == " " || firstStatement == "" || firstStatement == " "){
    return;
  } else {
    if(!filter.isProfane(firstStatement) && !filter.isProfane(secondStatement)){
      var finalFirstStatement = firstStatement;
      var finalSecondStatement = capitalizeFirstLetter(unrefinedSecondStatement);
      writeStatementToLTM(finalFirstStatement, finalSecondStatement);
      updateLTMArrays();
      console.clear();
    } else {
      console.log("Rude!");
    }
  }
}
```

/answer is the one that remembers the session.lastQuestion cookie.
Anyways, even though I'm using cookies, session.lastQuestion is updated for every client when one client updates it, resulting in desyncing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call both `res.sendFile()` and `res.render()` in the same request handler - pick one or the other.  Both are trying to send a response to the incoming http request, but you only get to send one response per request.  This is why you get the warning from Express "Can't set headers after they are sent." because when you go to send the second response, it sees that a response has already been sent and it encounters that when it tries to send the headers for the 2nd response.

If you think about it logically, the browser is making a request and will then display the response.  Once it gets a response, the request is done.  It is not expecting you to send yet another response and, in fact, Express won't allow you to send another response (thus why you get the warning you do).

Comment: I have other handlers that do, such as:
```app.post("/prompt", (req, res) => {
 console.log("New prompt: " + req.body.inputOne);
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
  lastQuestion = generateQuestion();
 res.render(__dirname + '/public/index.html', {response: evaluatePrompt(req.body.inputOne.toLowerCase()), question: lastQuestion, instructions: false});
});```
That work just fine. The problems starts when I use req.session and ends when I remove it.

Comment: @oliver -  It is wrong to send multiple responses to the same request.  It is.  I'd have to see your whole code in order to debug why you say it works sometimes and doesn't sometimes or why you think it has anything to do with the session.  Your design of sending multiple responses is just wrong.  You need to fix that.  I don't even know what you think you're trying to accomplish as the browser is only going to ever get the first response you send.

Comment: I edited my post to include all of my express code, and even though there are no more errors, session.lastQuestion still updates for all clients one one client updates it.

Comment: @oliver - You're supposed to read/write `req.session.lastQuestion`, NOT `session.lastQuestion`.  See the code example in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65535070/localizing-variables-in-express) to you.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I forgot to add that when I use them correctly like that it gives me:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined because I use .toLowerCase on req.session.lastQuestion in the function that uses it as a parmeter.

Comment: @oliver - When you tell people there's an error, you should look YOURSELF at exactly why that error is occurring first and then if you get stuck, you can share what debugging you did, what you learned and where you got stuck in your diagnosis.   Attempt to help yourself first.  If the line of code causing this error is `req.body.inputOne.toLowerCase()`, then look at why `req.body.inputOne` is `undefined`.  FYI, you should NEVER be using client-sent parameters like that without first checking them for validity.  Otherwise, a rogue client can crash your server.

Comment: Ok, well sorry for not adding this but it only comes up when I have ```req.session.lastQuestion``` BECAUSE ```req.session.lastQuestion``` returns as ```undefined```, and NOT ```req.body.inputOne```

Comment: @oliver - Well, it will be initially `undefined` until your code sets it to its first value.  If you look  in [my code example in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65535070/localizing-variables-in-express) to your previous question, you will see that I first check if the value is set before using it.  You need to do that too.  It is frustrating to me that you are ignoring my previous advice and code examples.

Comment: Ok well first I wanna apologize because I can totally understand how I might have been a pain, so I'm sorry for that, and you've been a lot of help, although it's been hard to read and remember everything since my head has been kinda cloudy lately, I have a lot of school stuff, so a lot of things in the background. Anyways, that makes sense, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: I realized that before I ever read it, in all the functions I assign it to generateQuestion() first, so that rules out that, do you know how else this might be fixed? (Sorry for two comments btw)

Comment: @Oliver - I can't really help without seeing the latest version of the code.  Can you add the entire current code to the end of your question (don't remove what is there already). I also need to know exactly which line of code the error occurs on.

Comment: Done! I marked the line with a comment and added the function using .toLowerCase

Comment: @Oliver - I EXPLICITLY asked you to NOT remove the existing code already in your question.  Questions here need to remain as they originally were and you can then ADD more info to it at the end.  That's how things work here.  You're just not listening to me at all.  I'm going to go do something else for awhile.  You need to fix your question and restore what you originally asked.  The point here is that you don't change the question to an entirely new question in the middle of things.

Comment: OK. I'm sorry. It's late, and I'm tired. Here's the updated version. Sorry for wierd formatting.

Comment: Ok, It's a new day, I'm less tired, I'll try to read and follow instructions more explicitly. I added the old code back.